# R ggplot: different colors for different groups in repeated measures design

Tags: r, ggplot2, linechart

I created a line chart in R for my repeated measures design with two groups (baseline and treatment). The grouping variable is called 'condition'. How do I get the two lines to have different colors?

```
ggplot(data = DataXY) +
  aes(x = Number, y = Score, group = Condition) +
  stat_summary(aes(linetype = Condition), fun = mean, geom = "line", colour = "#FC4E07", linewidth = 1) +
  stat_summary(fun.data = mean_sd, geom = "errorbar", colour = "#FC4E07", width = 0.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from = -1, to = 8, by = 1)) +
  labs(x = "Number", y = "rating", linetype = "Condition") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.direction = "horizontal",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5),
        text = element_text(size = 11, family = "Calibri"))
```

[image: line chart]

Thank you very much for your help,
Lucy

I could only find solutions to change the color overall, so for both lines at the same time

Comment: If you want different colors then map on the `color` aes, i.e. try `stat_summary(aes(linetype = Condition, color = Condition), ...)` and drop `colour = "#FC4E07"`. If you want to set custom colors you can do so via `scale_color_manual(values = ...)`

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.